Singular information matrix in lrm.fit when only modelling one variable
I am I am trying to fit a logistic regression to my dataset with the variable binary as the response variable of the date haul_date.
dat = 
mylogit = glm(binary ~ haul_date, data = dat, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(mylogit)

lrm(binary~haul_date, data = dat, y = TRUE, x = TRUE)

When running lrm() from the rms package, I get the error:
> lrm(binary~haul_date, data = dat, y = TRUE, x = TRUE)
singular information matrix in lrm.fit (rank= 1 ).  Offending variable(s):
haul_date 
Warning in lrm(binary ~ haul_date, data = dat, y = TRUE, x = TRUE) :
  Unable to fit model using “lrm.fit”
Error in 1:ns : argument of length 0

Having read through other examples of this problem , my guess is that there is an element of redundancy in my data. If someone has an idea about how I should manipulate my data to rectify the problem or another statistical approach, it would be greatly appreciated!
My data:

dat = structure(list(binary = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), haul_date = c(18127, 18127, 18127, 18127, 
18127, 18179, 18179, 18179, 18179, 18179, 18179, 18179, 18179, 
18179, 18179, 18194, 18194, 18194, 18194, 18194, 18194, 18198, 
18198, 18449, 18449, 18449, 18450, 18450, 18450, 18450, 18450, 
18450, 18450, 18450, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 
18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 
18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 
18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18459, 18459, 18459, 18459, 
18459, 18459, 18459, 18459, 18459, 18459, 18484, 18485, 18485, 
18485, 18485, 18485, 18485, 18485, 18485, 18485, 18486, 18486, 
18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 
18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18488, 18488, 
18488, 18488, 18488, 18488, 18488, 18493, 18493, 18493, 18492, 
18492, 18493, 18492, 18492, 18493, 18493, 18493, 18493, 18494, 
18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18495, 18495, 18495, 
18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 
18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18537, 18537, 
18537, 18537, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 
18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18542, 18542, 
18542, 18542, 18542, 18542, 18542, 18542, 18542, 18542, 18542, 
18542, 18542, 18543, 18543, 18543, 18557, 18557, 18557, 18557, 
18557, 18557, 18557, 18557, 18557, 18557, 18557, 18557, 18557, 
18557, 18558, 18557, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 
18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18558, 18571, 18571, 18571, 18571, 
18571, 18571, 18571, 18572, 18572, 18572, 18572, 18572, 18572, 
18572, 18572, 18572, 18813, 18813, 18813, 18813, 18813, 18815, 
18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18816, 18816, 18816, 18816, 
18816, 18816, 18816, 18816, 18816, 18816, 18817, 18817, 18817, 
18827, 18827, 18827, 18827, 18827, 18827, 18827, 18828, 18828, 
18828, 18828, 18828, 18828, 18828, 18828, 18828, 18828, 18828, 
18828, 18828, 18828, 18829, 18829, 18829, 18829, 18829, 18829, 
18829, 18829, 18829, 18829, 18829, 18829, 18829, 18829, 18830, 
18830, 18830, 18830, 18830, 18830, 18830, 18830, 18830, 18830, 
18830, 18831, 18831, 18831, 18841, 18841, 18841, 18841, 18841, 
18841, 18841, 18841, 18841, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18842, 
18842, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18843, 18843, 18843, 
18843, 18843, 18843, 18843, 18843, 18843, 18843, 18843, 18843, 
18843, 18844, 18844, 18844, 18844, 18844, 18844, 18844, 18844, 
18844, 18844, 18844, 18885, 18885, 18885, 18885, 18885, 18885, 
18885, 18885, 18885, 18885, 18885, 18885, 18885, 18891, 18891, 
18891, 18891, 18891, 18891, 18893, 18893, 18893, 18893, 18892, 
18892, 18892, 18892, 18893, 18893, 18893, 18893, 18893, 18893, 
18893, 18893, 18893, 18893, 19150, 19150, 19150, 19150, 19150, 
19150, 19150, 19151, 19151, 19151, 19151, 19151, 19151, 19151, 
19151, 19151, 19151, 19151, 19152, 19152, 19152, 19152, 19152, 
19152, 19163, 19163, 19163, 19163, 19164, 19164, 19164, 19164, 
19164, 19164, 19164, 19164, 19165, 19165, 19165, 19165, 19165, 
19165, 19165, 19165, 19165, 19165, 19166, 19166, 19166, 19166, 
19166, 19166, 19166, 19166, 19166, 19166, 19166, 19166, 19166, 
19167, 19167, 19206, 19206, 19206, 19206, 19206, 19206, 19206, 
19207, 19207, 19207, 19207, 19207, 19207, 19207, 19207, 19207, 
19207, 19207, 19207, 19207, 19207, 19208, 19208, 19208, 19208, 
19208, 19208, 19208, 19208, 19208, 19208, 19208, 19208, 19208, 
19208, 19209, 19209, 19209, 19209, 19220, 19220, 19220, 19220, 
19220, 19220, 19220, 19220, 19220, 19220, 19220, 19220, 19220, 
19220, 19221, 19221, 19221, 19221, 19221, 19221, 19221, 19222, 
19222, 19222, 19222, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 
19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 
19234, 19234, 19234, 19234, 19235, 19235, 19235, 19235, 19235, 
19235, 19235, 19235, 19235, 19235, 19235, 19235, 19235, 19235, 
19235, 19236, 19236, 19236, 19236, 19236, 19236, 19242, 19242, 
19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 
19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 
19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19242, 19243, 
19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 
19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 
19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19243, 19268, 19268, 19268, 
19268, 19268, 19268, 19268, 19269, 19269, 19269, 19269, 19269, 
19269, 19269, 19467, 19467, 19467, 19467, 19467, 19467, 19467, 
19467, 19467, 19542, 19542, 19542, 19542, 19542, 19542, 19543, 
19543, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19545, 
19545, 19542, 19542, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19542, 19542, 
19542, 19542, 19542, 19542, 19542, 19543, 19543, 19543, 19543, 
19543, 19545, 19545, 19555, 19555, 19555, 19555, 19556, 19556, 
19556, 19556, 19556, 19556, 19557, 19557, 19558, 19558, 19558, 
19558, 19558, 19558, 19559, 19559, 19559, 19559, 19557, 19557, 
19557, 19557, 19557, 19557, 19558, 19558, 19558, 19591, 19591, 
19591, 19591, 19592, 19592, 19592, 19593, 19593, 19594, 19594, 
19594, 19591, 19591, 19592, 19591, 19592, 19591, 19592, 19594, 
19592, 19594, 19593, 19593, 19593, 19591, 19591, 19591, 19592, 
19593, 19593, 19593, 19592, 19593, 19594, 19594, 19591, 19591, 
19591, 19591, 19591, 19592, 19592, 19592, 19592, 19593, 19593, 
19608, 19608, 19608, 19608, 19608, 19608, 19608, 19606, 19606, 
19606, 19606, 19606, 19606, 19606, 19608, 19608, 19608, 19608, 
19606, 19606, 19606, 19606, 19607, 19607, 19607, 19607, 19607, 
19607, 19607, 19607, 19607, 19608, 19607, 19607, 19607, 19607, 
19607, 19607, 19607, 19607, 19607, 19607, 19606, 19606, 19606, 
19606, 19606, 19606, 19608, 19608, 19608, 19626, 19626, 19627, 
19627, 19627, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 
19628, 19628, 19629, 19629, 19629, 19629, 19626, 19626, 19626, 
19626, 19627, 19627, 19627, 19627, 19628, 19628, 19626, 19626, 
19627, 19627, 19626, 19626, 19626, 19627, 19629, 19629, 19629, 
19629, 19626, 19626, 19626, 19627, 19627, 19627, 19627, 19628, 
19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 19628, 
19628, 19629, 19629, 19629, 19626, 19626, 19626, 19626, 19627, 
19627, 19627, 19627, 19627, 19633, 19633, 19633, 19634, 19634, 
19634, 19634, 19635, 19635, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19635, 
19635, 19635, 19633, 19633, 19634, 19635, 19635, 19633, 19633, 
19634, 19634, 19634, 19635, 19635, 19635, 19634, 19633, 19634, 
19634, 19634, 19634, 19635, 19635, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 
19634, 19635, 19635, 19649, 19649, 19649, 19649, 19649, 19650, 
19647, 19649, 19647, 19649, 19649, 19649, 19649, 19649, 19649, 
19649, 19649, 19650, 19650, 19647)), row.names = c(NA, -918L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


The tolerance for testing singularity is a bit too loose for your data, because your haul_date has a mean much larger than its range.  You usually don't see this sort of problem with modern computers, but it may be that the  use of lrm for ordinal models requires that sort of sensitivity
You can tighten the tolerance:
> lrm(binary~haul_date, data = dat, y = TRUE, x = TRUE, tol=1e-10)
Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = binary ~ haul_date, data = dat, x = TRUE, y = TRUE, 
    tol = 1e-10)

                       Model Likelihood      Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                             Ratio Test             Indexes          Indexes    
Obs           918    LR chi2      25.71      R2       0.042    C       0.617    
 0            210    d.f.             1      R2(1,918)0.027    Dxy     0.235    
 1            708    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    R2(1,485.9)0.050    gamma   0.238    
max |deriv| 4e-09                            Brier    0.172    tau-a   0.083    

          Coef     S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept -15.8605 3.3922 -4.68  <0.0001 
haul_date   0.0009 0.0002  5.02  <0.0001 

or recenter your haul_date variable. Here I've subtracted off the mininum value, so it now goes from 0 to 1523 instead of 18127 to 19650
> lrm(binary~I(haul_date-18127), data = dat, y = TRUE, x = TRUE)
Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = binary ~ I(haul_date - 18127), data = dat, x = TRUE, 
    y = TRUE)

                       Model Likelihood      Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                             Ratio Test             Indexes          Indexes    
Obs           918    LR chi2      25.71      R2       0.042    C       0.617    
 0            210    d.f.             1      R2(1,918)0.027    Dxy     0.235    
 1            708    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    R2(1,485.9)0.050    gamma   0.238    
max |deriv| 3e-10                            Brier    0.172    tau-a   0.083    

          Coef   S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept 0.3842 0.1763 2.18   0.0293  
haul_date 0.0009 0.0002 5.02   <0.0001 

(Perhaps Frank Harrell will pop up and explain why the tolerance is set that way)
